# Need some information about Crawl Anywhere and solr

Tags: solr, tomcat7, web-crawler

I gone through the crawl anywhere documentation but i am very much confuse about its installation steps.

1. What i understood is Apache is optional. But do need independent tomcat instance for crawl? Because what i saw in folder structure, there is tomcat folder already present and war file is also there?
2. Also do we need independent instance of Apache solr also ?
3. If we want to add postgresql database to crawl, how we can do that?

Please provide some link also so that I can go through it and clarify any doubt I have in my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Apache is needed to use admin interface. Tomcat is needed for some interactive features. You can crawl without both of them.
2. No.
3. MySQL and MongoDB are supported. The code is open source, so you can add postgresql support.

Try [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/crawl-anywhere) for other questions

Comment: @klein: "You can crawl without both of them." ---i not able to follow you on this.. can you explain it. Is there any way we can test whether we are crawling the documents perfectly or not.. any functionality?